# How to launch SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: sql, windows, configurationmanager

I've problem on launching SQL Server Configuration Manager on Windows Server 2008 R2, where the "All Programs" was disabled from the Start Menu.

Is there any other way launch it? I cant find it from the Search as well.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: For Sql Server 2008, are you tried `SQLServerManager10.msc`?

Comment: ya, it can be launch, thanks RRUZ

Answer (score 2):

For Sql Server 2008 you can use `SQLServerManager10.msc`